# How to change the object key from nested array object and return array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops, object

I have an array `arr1` and an object `arr2` with a nested `config` array.

If the object of `arr1` has a key that matches with an `id` in that nested `config` and deeper `questions` array, then change that key (in the `arr1` object) with the `title` property that is found next to that `id`.

Here is an example. The key `isWorking` from `arr1` is the same as `arr2.config[0].questions[0].id` value, so
change that `isWorking` key to the value found in `arr2.config[0].questions[0].custom.title`.

```
var arr1= [
  {"jobs": "Marketing","isWorking": yes,"country": "MY"},
  {"country": "IN","members": 4}
]

var arr2=
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"xxx",
   "config":[
      {
         "questions":[
            {
               "id":"isWorking",
               "custom":{
                  "title":"Are you working?"
               }
            },
            {
               "id":"jobs",
               "custom":{
                  "title":"Please specify job(s)"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "questions":[
            {
               "id":"country",
               "custom":{
                  "title":"which Country?"
               }
            },
            {
               "id":"members",
               "type":"choices",
               "custom":{
                  "title":"How many members?"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {"Please specify job(s)": "Marketing","Are you working": yes,"which Country": "MY"},
  {"which Country": "IN","How many members": 4}
]
```

I tried:

```
var result = arr1.map(e => ({
  arr2.config.find(i => {
    i.questions.find( q => {
     q.id === Object.key(e) ? Object.key(e) === q.custom.title : q.id
   }
 })
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code the `find` callbacks do not return anything. When you have a code block (with braces) you need a `return` statement. Also, the outer object literal which you have as the return value of the `map` callback cannot have just the `find` call in it. It should have the proper object literal syntax, like with spread syntax. Moreover, the `find` method can only return an existing object, not a new, modified one.

I will assume here that the matching strings for the first object have to be found in the *first* `questions` array, and for the second object in the second `questions` array.

I also propose to rename `arr2`, because it isn't an array. It is a plain object, with a property that is an array (`config`).

Here is how you could do it with `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries`:

```js
const arr1 = [{"jobs": "Marketing","isWorking": "yes","country": "MY"}, {"country": "IN","members": 4}];

const obj = {"id":1,"name":"xxx","config":[{"questions":[{"id":"isWorking","custom":{"title":"Are you working?"}},{"id":"jobs","custom":{"title":"Please specify job(s)"}}]},{"questions":[{"id":"country","custom":{"title":"which Country?"}},{"id":"members","type":"choices","custom":{"title":"How many members?"}}]}]}

const result = arr1.map((e, i) => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(e).map(([key, value]) =>
        [obj.config[i].questions.find(({id}) =>
            key === id
         )?.custom?.title ?? key, value]
    )
))

console.log(result);
```